# What numbers that I can put in numpy.random.seed()?

Tags: python, numpy-random

I have noticed that you can put various numbers inside of `numpy.random.seed()`, for example `numpy.random.seed(1)`, `numpy.random.seed(101)`. What do the different numbers mean? How do you choose the numbers?

Comment: Doesn't really matter as it just determines what the subsequent "random" sequence will be. Useful for testing so the values don't vary from run-to-run. I usually use `42`...

Answer (score 13):

Consider a very basic random number generator:

```
Z[i] = (a*Z[i-1] + c) % m
```

Here, `Z[i]` is the `ith` random number, `a` is the multiplier and `c` is the increment - for different `a`, `c` and `m` combinations you have different generators. This is known as the [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) introduced by Lehmer. The remainder of that division, or modulus (`%`), will generate a number between zero and `m-1` and by setting `U[i] = Z[i] / m` you get random numbers between zero and one.

As you may have noticed, in order to start this generative process - in order to have a `Z[1]` you need to have a `Z[0]` - an initial value. This initial value that starts the process is called the seed. Take a look at this example:

[image]

The initial value, the seed is determined as 7 to start the process. However, that value is not used to generate a random number. Instead, it is used to generate the first `Z`.

The most important feature of a pseudo-random number generator would be its unpredictability. Generally, as long as you don't share your seed, you are fine with all seeds as the generators today are much more complex than this. However, as a further step you can generate the seed randomly as well. You can skip the first `n` numbers as another alternative.

Main source: Law, A. M. (2007). Simulation modeling and analysis. Tata McGraw-Hill.

Comment: I like this answer.  Few things though: "most important feature... is unpredictability": you might want algorithmic reproducibility (because you're doing modelling not security) in which case you want the opposite - predictability. Also: How does one generate a seed randomly before they have a seed to generate random numbers with? Take the timestamp of the recursion-overflow exception that was raised :)? Also, numpy explicitely does not use that random generator - does this advice hold for numpy's random module, which was asked about?

Comment: I agree that reproducibility is very important- that's why we share seeds but that reproducibility does not exactly mean predictability I think. The numbers would still have the uniformity and independence features. They wouldn't be predicted only using those numbers. They could be *calculated* knowing the underlying process.

Comment: For defining the seed: AFAIK many applications are using something similar to what you desribed: nanoseconds of the current time mod some other thing, etc. Python is using Mersenne-Twister, and I'm not sure but possibly numpy is also using that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister It is different from linear congruential generators but it also has this recursive process so as long as you have something called a seed to start a process, the same logic should apply, IMHO. :)

Answer (score 8):

The short answer:

There are three ways to `seed()` a random number generator in `numpy.random`:

- use no argument or use `None` -- the RNG initializes itself from the OS's random number generator (which generally is cryptographically random)
- use some 32-bit integer N -- the RNG will use this to initialize its state based on a deterministic function (same seed → same state)
- use an array-like sequence of 32-bit integers n<sub>0</sub>, n<sub>1</sub>, n<sub>2</sub>, etc. -- again, the RNG will use this to initialize its state based on a deterministic function (same values for seed → same state). This is intended to be done with a hash function of sorts, although there are magic numbers in the source code and it's not clear why they are doing what they're doing.

If you want to do something repeatable and simple, use a single integer.

If you want to do something repeatable but unlikely for a third party to guess, use a tuple or a list or a numpy array containing some sequence of 32-bit integers. You could, for example, use `numpy.random` with a seed of `None` to generate a bunch of 32-bit integers (say, 32 of them, which would generate a total of 1024 bits) from the OS's RNG, store in some seed `S` which you save in some secret place, then use that seed to generate whatever sequence R of pseudorandom numbers you wish. Then you can later recreate that sequence by re-seeding with `S` again, and as long as you keep the value of `S` secret (as well as the generated numbers R), no one would be able to reproduce that sequence R. If you just use a single integer, there's only 4 billion possibilities and someone could potentially try them all. That may be a bit on the paranoid side, but you could do it.

---

Longer answer

The `numpy.random` module uses the [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) algorithm, which you can confirm yourself in one of two ways:

- Either by looking at the documentation for [`numpy.random.RandomState`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.html#numpy.random.RandomState), of which `numpy.random` uses an instance for the `numpy.random.*` functions (but you can also use an isolated independent instance of)
- Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/master/numpy/random/mtrand) in [mtrand.pyx](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx) which uses something called Pyrex to wrap a fast C implementation, and [randomkit.c](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/mtrand/randomkit.c) and [initarray.c](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/mtrand/initarray.c).

In any case here's what the `numpy.random.RandomState` documentation says about `seed()`:

> *Compatibility Guarantee* A fixed seed and a fixed series of calls to `RandomState` methods using the same parameters will always produce the same results up to roundoff error except when the values were incorrect. Incorrect values will be fixed and the NumPy version in which the fix was made will be noted in the relevant docstring. Extension of existing parameter ranges and the addition of new parameters is allowed as long the previous behavior remains unchanged.
>
> **Parameters:
>
>   seed** *: {None, int, array_like}, optional*
>
> Random seed used to initialize the pseudo-random number generator. Can be any integer between 0 and 2**32 - 1 inclusive, an array (or other sequence) of such integers, or `None` (the default). If seed is `None`, then RandomState will try to read data from `/dev/urandom` (or the Windows analogue) if available or seed from the clock otherwise.

It doesn't say how the seed is used, but if you dig into the source code it refers to the `init_by_array` function: (docstring elided)

```
def seed(self, seed=None):
    cdef rk_error errcode
    cdef ndarray obj "arrayObject_obj"
    try:
        if seed is None:
            with self.lock:
                errcode = rk_randomseed(self.internal_state)
        else:
            idx = operator.index(seed)
            if idx > int(2**32 - 1) or idx < 0:
                raise ValueError("Seed must be between 0 and 2**32 - 1")
            with self.lock:
                rk_seed(idx, self.internal_state)
    except TypeError:
        obj = np.asarray(seed).astype(np.int64, casting='safe')
        if ((obj > int(2**32 - 1)) | (obj < 0)).any():
            raise ValueError("Seed must be between 0 and 2**32 - 1")
        obj = obj.astype('L', casting='unsafe')
        with self.lock:
            init_by_array(self.internal_state, <unsigned long *>PyArray_DATA(obj),
                PyArray_DIM(obj, 0))
```

And here's what the `init_by_array` function looks like:

```
extern void
init_by_array(rk_state *self, unsigned long init_key[], npy_intp key_length)
{
    /* was signed in the original code. RDH 12/16/2002 */
    npy_intp i = 1;
    npy_intp j = 0;
    unsigned long *mt = self->key;
    npy_intp k;

    init_genrand(self, 19650218UL);
    k = (RK_STATE_LEN > key_length ? RK_STATE_LEN : key_length);
    for (; k; k--) {
        /* non linear */
        mt[i] = (mt[i] ^ ((mt[i - 1] ^ (mt[i - 1] >> 30)) * 1664525UL))
            + init_key[j] + j;
        /* for > 32 bit machines */
        mt[i] &= 0xffffffffUL;
        i++;
        j++;
        if (i >= RK_STATE_LEN) {
            mt[0] = mt[RK_STATE_LEN - 1];
            i = 1;
        }
        if (j >= key_length) {
            j = 0;
        }
    }
    for (k = RK_STATE_LEN - 1; k; k--) {
        mt[i] = (mt[i] ^ ((mt[i-1] ^ (mt[i-1] >> 30)) * 1566083941UL))
             - i; /* non linear */
        mt[i] &= 0xffffffffUL; /* for WORDSIZE > 32 machines */
        i++;
        if (i >= RK_STATE_LEN) {
            mt[0] = mt[RK_STATE_LEN - 1];
            i = 1;
        }
    }

    mt[0] = 0x80000000UL; /* MSB is 1; assuring non-zero initial array */
    self->gauss = 0;
    self->has_gauss = 0;
    self->has_binomial = 0;
}
```

This essentially "munges" the random number state in a nonlinear, hash-like method using each value within the provided sequence of seed values.

Answer (score 5):

What is normally called a random number sequence in reality is a "pseudo-random" number sequence because the values are computed using a deterministic algorithm and probability plays no real role.

The "seed" is a starting point for the sequence and the guarantee is that if you start from the same seed you will get the same sequence of numbers. This is very useful for example for debugging (when you are looking for an error in a program you need to be able to reproduce the problem and study it, a non-deterministic program would be much harder to debug because every run would be different).

Answer (score 0):

Basically the number guarantees the same 'randomness' every time.

More properly, the number is a seed, which can be an integer, an array (or other sequence) of integers of any length, or the default (none). If seed is none, then random will try to read data from /dev/urandom if available or make a seed from the clock otherwise.

Edit: In most honesty, as long as your program isn't something that needs to be super secure, it shouldn't matter what you pick. If this is the case, don't use these methods - use `os.urandom()` or `SystemRandom` if you require a cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator.

The most important concept to understand here is that of pseudo-randomness. Once you understand this idea, you can determine if your program really needs a seed etc. I'd recommend reading [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html).

Comment: This answer seems incomplete to me. Is it okay for me to write "random.seed(random.random())"? Is 7 better than 4? Is it just going to hash the array? Basically, what's going on here? "How do you choose the number" seems like the most important line in the question, imo

Comment: @en_Knight -- I just attempted to give this kind of detail in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the meaning of random seeds, you need to first understand the "pseudo-random" number sequence because the values are computed using a deterministic algorithm.

So you can think of this number as a starting value to calulate the next number you get from the random generator. Putting the same value here will make your program getting the same "random" value everytime, so your program becomes deterministic.

As said in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7030595/6238076)

> they (`numpy.random` and `random.random`) both use the Mersenne twister sequence to generate their random numbers, and they're both completely deterministic - that is, if you know a few key bits of information, it's possible to predict with absolute certainty what number will come next.

If you really care about randomness, ask the user to generate some noise (some arbitary words) or just put the system time as seed.

If your codes run on Intel CPU (or AMD with newest chips) I also suggest you to check the [RdRand](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rdrand/0.9.0) package which uses the cpu instruction `rdrand` to collect "true" (hardware) randomness.

Refs:

1. [Random seed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed)
2. [What is a seed in terms of generating a random number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14914657/6238076)

Comment: This seems important: "If you really care about randomness, ask the user to generate some noise (some arbitary words) or just put the system time as seed" but I think I buy only half of that. Seems like users might "randomly" pick similar common words every time - ppl aren't great at being random. Time is pretty solid advice. But there isn't enough here for me to know what to do - e.g., based on what you've written it seems wise for me to continue resetting the seed in session to ensure super unpredictable randomness, when in fact doing so would be counterproductive

Comment: I didn't suggest continue resetting is good. In contrast, I think you should set the seed **only once**. The key point is to prevent attacker from guessing your random number. If the someone can guess your seed of the first time then I assume he/she can also know the rest.

Comment: I don't see any security tag.. numpy is used for modelling and simulation a lot, and if that's the case then maybe we don't care attackers as much as being able to reproduce our experiments, right? My comment about "continue resetting" wasn't that you explicitly advocate *for* it, but that there isn't a lot of information here about how the seeds actually work. Imo, there should be enough info for me to know how to set a seed and what things are bad to do, if the question asks how to choose a seed, and there isn't anything here to dispel that common mistake, e.g.

Comment: I think this is actually a pretty good answer, I'm just looking for a little more before I upvote : )

Comment: I agree the context of this question should be scientific computing so I add the `RdRand` package here.

Answer (score 0):

One very specific answer: `np.random.seed` can take values from `0 and 2**32 - 1`, which interestingly differs from `random.seed` which can take any hashable object.

Answer (score 0):

A side comment: better set your seed to a rather large number but still within the generator limit. Doing so can let the seed number have a good balance of 0 and 1 bits. Avoid having many 0 bits in the seed.

Reference: pyTorch [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Generator.html?highlight=generator#torch.Generator)