# How to generate the same random sequence twice in java?

Tags: java, random

```
public class MazeBuilder implements Runnable {

    // class internal local variables
    protected SingleRandom random ; // random number stream, used to make randomized decisions, e.g for direction to go
    Order order; // describes what is wanted, e.g. a perfect maze or not    
    /**
     * Constructor for a randomized maze generation
     */
    public MazeBuilder(){
        random = SingleRandom.getRandom();
    }
    /**
     * Constructor with option to make maze generation deterministic or random
     */
    public MazeBuilder(boolean deterministic){
        if (true == deterministic)
        {
            this.random = random ;
        }


    random = SingleRandom.getRandom();
}
```

The first constructor randomly generates a maze. I need to implement code so that if MazeBuilder.build is called for the same skill level twice, it will deliver the same results. I think "this.random = random ;" in the second constructor will do this, but I'm not sure this is correct.

Comment: What is SingleRandom?

Comment: Do you mean using the same **random seed**?

Comment: Usually you use the same seed.

Comment: The beauty of this question... `generate the same random sequence twice`

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve is actually called **random seed**.
If you initialize `Random` with the same seed, then you will get the same sequence every time.

Read more about what random seed is [at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed) or [at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914595/what-is-a-seed-in-terms-of-generating-a-random-number).

You can simply do something like this:

```
public class MazeBuilder
{
    private Random _random;

    public MazeBuilder()
    {
        _random = new Random();
    }

    public MazeBuilder(int seed)
    {
        _random = new Random(seed);
    }

    public void generateMaze()
    {
        // here you use _random.next()
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if my code is quite correct - I am not a Java, but C# developer. Please, let me know, if there any errors :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a class like [this](https://github.com/Jesavino/AMazeApp/blob/master/src/falstad/SingleRandom.java) or something similar, try this:

```
private static final int SEED = 1234; // or any other int

/**
 * Constructor with option to make maze generation deterministic or random
 */
public MazeBuilder(boolean deterministic) {
    random = SingleRandom.getRandom();
    if (deterministic) {
        random.setSeed(SEED);
    }
}
```

By calling `setSeed()` with a hard-coded value, you'll ensure that it follows the same sequence on every run.

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what my class looks like and this seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you generate random numbers and what `SingleRandom` object is
but in java there is a `Random` class => https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

in which a `setSeed` method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#setSeed(long) 

works in such a way that:

> it alters the state of this random number generator object so as to
>   be in exactly the same state as if it had just been created with the
>   argument seed as a seed.

The below code resets the `random` objects using `setSeed`, and in this way it generates twice the same stream of random numbers:

```
 Random rand = new Random();

  rand.setSeed(3);
  for( int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
      System.out.println( rand.nextInt());
  }

  System.out.println( "=============");

  rand.setSeed(3);
  for( int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
      System.out.println( rand.nextInt());
  }

-1155099828
-1879439976
304908421
-836442134
288278256
-1795872892
-995758198
-1824734168
976394918
-634239373
=============
-1155099828
-1879439976
304908421
-836442134
288278256
-1795872892
-995758198
-1824734168
976394918
-634239373
```